# Get product attribute labels from variations of a variable product in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy, product-variations

I  create a sample 'woocommerce' product list, then the single product page has didn't get the attribute label of the product. below show the code

```
<?php if ( !$product->variations ) {return;}$field_name = isset($field_name) ? $field_name :'';$calendar_id = isset($calendar_id) ? $calendar_id : 0; <?php if ( $field_name ):?><?php foreach($product->variations as $variation_id => $variation_data):?><?php echo $variation_data['variation_title'];?><?php endforeach ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

> The variables `$field_name` and `$calendar_id` are not defined in your code, so I don't use them.

Your code seems to be outdated since Woocommerce 3. From a variable product object, to get the variation attributes label names / term names pairs, use the following:

```
<?php 
if ( $product->is_type('variable') && $variations = $product->get_available_variations() ) {
    $field_name  = isset($field_name)  ? $field_name  : '';
    $calendar_id = isset($calendar_id) ? $calendar_id :  0;

    if ( sizeof( $variations ) > 0 ) {

        // Loop through available product variations
        foreach( $variations as $variation ) {

            // Get variation title
            $variation_title = get_the_title( $variation['variation_id'] );

            // Display variation title
            echo '<p><strong>Title:</strong> ' . $variation_title . '</p>';

            // Loop through variation attributtes
            foreach( $variation['attributes'] as $variation_attribute => $term_slug ){
                // Get attribute taxonomy name
                $taxonomy   = str_replace( 'attribute_', '', $variation_attribute );

                // Get attribute label name
                $label_name = wc_attribute_label($taxonomy);
                // Get attribute term name value
                $term_name = ( $term = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $taxonomy ) ) ? $term->name : $term_slug;

                // Display attribute label / term name pairs
                echo '<p><strong>' . $label_name . ':</strong> ' . $term_name . '</p>';
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Tested and works in Woocommerce 3+